# How to convert a dataframe into the dataframe for Apriori Algorithm

Tags: python, pandas, algorithm, apriori

I have a dataframe look like this [image]

My goal is to find what products are sold together the most. Therefore, I decided to use Apriori Algorithm so I'm trying to convert a dataframe into something look like this
[image]

What would be the best way to do so?

If there is a better way to find what I'm trying to find, I would be grateful if you suggest me another way.

Comment: this guide goes over the data prep you'll need https://pbpython.com/market-basket-analysis.html

Answer (score 0):

Just group by ID and get a list of products, feed an array of those into apriori.

```
from apyori import apriori

df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1,2,1,2,3,2], 'product':['ball','bat','bat','car','baloon','ball']})

list(apriori(df.groupby('ID')['product'].apply(list).values))
```

Output

```
[RelationRecord(items=frozenset({'ball'}), support=0.6666666666666666, ordered_statistics=[OrderedStatistic(items_base=frozenset(), items_add=frozenset({'ball'}), confidence=0.6666666666666666, lift=1.0)]),
 RelationRecord(items=frozenset({'baloon'}), support=0.3333333333333333, ordered_statistics=[OrderedStatistic(items_base=frozenset(), items_add=frozenset({'baloon'}), confidence=0.3333333333333333, lift=1.0)]),
 RelationRecord(items=frozenset({'bat'}), support=0.6666666666666666, ordered_statistics=[OrderedStatistic(items_base=frozenset(), items_add=frozenset({'bat'}), confidence=0.6666666666666666, lift=1.0)]),
 RelationRecord(items=frozenset({'car'}), support=0.3333333333333333, ordered_statistics=[OrderedStatistic(items_base=frozenset(), items_add=frozenset({'car'}), confidence=0.3333333333333333, lift=1.0)]),
 RelationRecord(items=frozenset({'bat', 'ball'}), support=0.6666666666666666, ordered_statistics=[OrderedStatistic(items_base=frozenset(), items_add=frozenset({'bat', 'ball'}), confidence=0.6666666666666666, lift=1.0), OrderedStatistic(items_base=frozenset({'ball'}), items_add=frozenset({'bat'}), confidence=1.0, lift=1.5), OrderedStatistic(items_base=frozenset({'bat'}), items_add=frozenset({'ball'}), confidence=1.0, lift=1.5)]),
 RelationRecord(items=frozenset({'ball', 'car'}), support=0.3333333333333333, ordered_statistics=[OrderedStatistic(items_base=frozenset(), items_add=frozenset({'ball', 'car'}), confidence=0.3333333333333333, lift=1.0), OrderedStatistic(items_base=frozenset({'ball'}), items_add=frozenset({'car'}), confidence=0.5, lift=1.5), OrderedStatistic(items_base=frozenset({'car'}), items_add=frozenset({'ball'}), confidence=1.0, lift=1.5)]),
 RelationRecord(items=frozenset({'bat', 'car'}), support=0.3333333333333333, ordered_statistics=[OrderedStatistic(items_base=frozenset(), items_add=frozenset({'bat', 'car'}), confidence=0.3333333333333333, lift=1.0), OrderedStatistic(items_base=frozenset({'bat'}), items_add=frozenset({'car'}), confidence=0.5, lift=1.5), OrderedStatistic(items_base=frozenset({'car'}), items_add=frozenset({'bat'}), confidence=1.0, lift=1.5)]),
 RelationRecord(items=frozenset({'bat', 'ball', 'car'}), support=0.3333333333333333, ordered_statistics=[OrderedStatistic(items_base=frozenset(), items_add=frozenset({'bat', 'ball', 'car'}), confidence=0.3333333333333333, lift=1.0), OrderedStatistic(items_base=frozenset({'ball'}), items_add=frozenset({'bat', 'car'}), confidence=0.5, lift=1.5), OrderedStatistic(items_base=frozenset({'bat'}), items_add=frozenset({'ball', 'car'}), confidence=0.5, lift=1.5), OrderedStatistic(items_base=frozenset({'car'}), items_add=frozenset({'bat', 'ball'}), confidence=1.0, lift=1.5), OrderedStatistic(items_base=frozenset({'bat', 'ball'}), items_add=frozenset({'car'}), confidence=0.5, lift=1.5), OrderedStatistic(items_base=frozenset({'ball', 'car'}), items_add=frozenset({'bat'}), confidence=1.0, lift=1.5), OrderedStatistic(items_base=frozenset({'bat', 'car'}), items_add=frozenset({'ball'}), confidence=1.0, lift=1.5)])]
```